# Local Lipschitz continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In some proof I have seen the author use that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded, then it is locally Lipschitz continuous. I have never seen that before and I don't find any proof. Thank you.

Comment: It's not true. Was it perhaps that $f$ is continuously differentiable? Or differentiable with a (locally) bounded derivative?

Comment: Nope. The author wants to prove the differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with f as above and $f(x)=0$ for an infinite number of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has a maximal solution for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. He argues that $f$ continuous and bounded implies locally Lipschitz and therefore there is a maximal solution via Picard–Lindelöf theorem.

Comment: It's plain false. We get a maximal solution (defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$) by existence theorems with weaker hypotheses than Picard-Lindelöf, but from continuity and boundedness, you can't get local Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: $f$ being continuous and bounded implies that $x$ is locally Lipschitz. Maybe if you gave a reference to that proof, someone would be able to explain the actual proof, not your interpretation of it.

Answer (score 0):

That seems false to me. Look at 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x \sin \frac{1}{x^2} & x \ne 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

On the interval $[-1, 1]$ it's bounded and continuous, and can be extended to a continuous function by constants outside that interval.

But I don't believe it's locally Lipschitz near zero, because the derivative, as you approach zero,  is unbounded.

Comment: It's certainly false and that's a counterexample. It's not quite right to say the derivative "approaches" $\pm\infty$ at the origin; what's correct is to say the derivative is unbounded near the origin.